# Calculations for my Portfolio

Tags: investing, portfolio, cryptocurrency

First excuse my maths and limited finance knowledge.

I am testing investing in crypto and trying to calculate my ROIs, Profit/Loss etc and getting stuck a bit and was wondering if anyone can help!

First example
Lets say i buy

> 10 BTC for 100 USD/ coin on 1st of January making the total investment
> of 1000 USD

*i know we all wish*

Lets say the `Current Value for BTC is 300 USD/coin`

My `Profit/Loss will be 2000USD` which is `3000 (current value) - 1000 (initial investment)`

My `ROI is 2000/1000` which is `2%`

I think so far i am on the right track!

Now my first question is
Lets say i buy

```
10 BTC for 250 USD / coin on 5th of Jan
```

How do i factor in

1. My Profit Loss
2. My ROI

My Second question is
Lets say i **SELL**

```
5 BTC for 150 USD / coin on 10th of Jan
```

Again how do i factor in my

1. My Profit Loss
2. My ROI

I think what i am missing is how i calculate my Total Invested amount.

And my third question is how do i calculate my `Daily ROI` after buying and selling coins over time?

I appreciate that this is way too much to ask, so perhaps google terms to search for will suffice. As i think i am missed the correct terms to use in my searches.

Thanks

Comment: 2000/1000 is 200% not 2%

Comment: @BobBaerker isn't it 100% gain because it doubled?

Comment: If $1,000 doubled, it would be worth $2,000.  Started with $1,000 and it rose to $3,000.  Gain is $2,000.  That's 200%.

Comment: Do you really think you should be "investing in crypto"?

Comment: @BobBaerker i reckon it to be 2% i spent 1000 USD and the Current Value is 3000 USD so the result is 2000 when i divide it by 1000 my initial investment it returns 2%. how is it 200%?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey a question i keep asking myself too.

Comment: Two percent is .02 so multiply that by 1000 and get back to me :->)

Comment: @user3052526 2% ROI means $1,000 became $1,020. 1,000 * 1.02. Doing `2000/1000` is indeed 2.00; that's 200%. "Per cent".

Comment: @ceejayoz ahhhh alrighty thanks